# when changing the value of a variable what is the difference between using int x = 100; versus x = x + 100;

Tags: c++

Most of the time when changing the value of a variable, I will use (for example) `int x = 100;`, but when running the program it is not having the intended effect, and if I use `x = x + 100;` then it works

I am using this inside an `if` statement, and the former method of reassigning the variables value isn't having the intended effect.

```cpp
void Game::ComposeFrame(){
    int y = 200;
    int x = 400;
    int g = 0;


    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_DOWN)) {

        y = y + 150;

    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_UP)) {

        y = y - 150;

    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_RIGHT)) {

        x = x + 150;

    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_LEFT)) {

        x = x - 150;

    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_SHIFT)) {

        g = g + 100;

    }

    gfx.PutPixel(x + 1, y + 100, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 2, y + 100, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 3, y + 100, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 4, y + 100, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 5, y + 100, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 1, y + 105, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 2, y + 105, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 3, y + 105, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 4, y + 105, 100, g, g);
    gfx.PutPixel(x + 5, y + 105, 100, g, g);
```

The intended purpose of this program is, when run, it should place pixels on the screen, and when pushing certain buttons it should move those pixels around. When using `int x = 100;` the position of the pixels won't change, but it works as intended when using `x = x + 100;`

Comment: ... those do completely different things

Comment: Try both of them and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel the need to expand on the other answers...

`int x = 100;` creates a new variable called `x` which "shadows" (or hides) any previous variable(s) called `x` in enclosing scopes. This means the original value of `x` is unmodified (e.g. when the new `x`'s scope ends).

What you should use is `x = x + 100;` (or equivalently `x += 100;`) if you want to increase the current value of x by 100.

Now for the part no one else has mentioned yet:

> Most of the time when changing the value of a variable I will use (for example) int x = 100;

This means you frequently use this (almost-always) incorrect pattern of shadowing variables. Because having multiple **different** variables with the **same** name is confusing, even when employed correctly they can easily lead to unexpected behavior. Thus you should **never** shadow a variable. If you need this behavior, make its name slightly different (e.g. `x` and `_x`, etc.).

To help you in the future, you can use the `-Wshadow` compiler flag to issue warnings for all such occurrences at compile time (assuming you're using gcc, clang, or any of their offshoots).

Answer (score 1):

`int x = 100;` doesn't change a value of a variable. It defines a brand new variable, with a given initial value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `int x = 100` is defining an integer which is holding the value 100.
But using `x = x + 100` is just saying that you have already an integer(or some variable) which named x, and you just want to redefine your variable as x + 100.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the answer that truly answers the question for me. The reason it doesn't work when I redefine the variable within an if statement is because of scope. The scope of a variable or any information is the curly braces that it is contained in. The information of a variable within the scope of the curly braces it is declared in only exists that way in those curly braces. So when I REDEFINED the variable into a different 'lower' tier of scope the information of that variable won't be passed on beyond that scope UNLESS you change the existing variable without redefining it ie. x += 100; does not redefine the variable into a lower scope, it changes its value.